# java - Spring Mail Authentication Error

Tags: java, xml, spring, email

Intento realizar un servicio para el envío de emails desde mi aplicación. Tengo el Bean configurado de la siguiente manera:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class ="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl" >
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
        <property name="port" value="587"/>
        <property name="protocol" value="smtp"/>
        <property name="username" value="XXX@gmail.com"/>
        <property name="password" value="XXX"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.quitwait">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        </bean>
```

El problema viene cuando ejecuto el método mailSender.send(), que me salta la siguiente excepción:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
```

Siguiendo el comportamiento del programa con el debugger, veo que llega hasta el `transport.connect(getHost(), getPort(), username, password);` dentro de JavaMailSenderImpl.

los parámetros se corresponden correctamente con lo definido en mi fichero xml, entonces supongo que me está fallando el usuario o la contraseña. que se corresponden con mi cuenta de correo y su contraseña.

Ya tengo habilitado el acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras.
Muchas gracias.